# Insert generated key from one table into second table with batch in one request

Tags: sql, mariadb, generated

There are two tables with the dependence one to many on field occupation_id (project about booking hotel rooms). Each occupation entity can have several booked rooms. Is there way to do in a single sql request insertion to the first table (occupation) and several batch insertions to the second table(booked_rooms).

Tables are:

```
Table: Occupations
occupation_id bigint (autoincrement)
user_id bigint
check_in_date date
check_out_date date
status text

Table: Booked_rooms
booked_room_id bigint (autoincrement)
occupation_id bigint
beds int
class_rate int
```

Comment: You cannot update several tables in a single query. However you can execute several queries in the same database transaction and commit changes all together... Or you can use triggers to automate changes on related tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a transaction:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO ...;
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO ...;
COMMIT;
```